# Google cloud storage - Error on trying javascript sample

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage

I was watching the instructional video on how to handle google cloud storage via JavaScript in the link listed below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ytpvQJNOU8

I followed the instructions step by step (I hope) and although I manage to insert buckets and objects to bucket, I still fail to retrieve bucket lists or get them to be shown in the HTML body.

That's when I noticed that when I checked the drop-list element I get this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'wc' of undefined" which
>   links to line
>
> 483: getCodeSnippet(request.wc.wc.method, request.wc.wc.params);

Can you help me with this problem? Did I do something wrong?

Any help you can provide would be highly appreciated.

Link to the example is listed here:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-javascript-samples

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll answer my own question.

If you comment this code segment (lines 481 - 490)

```
 if (apiRequestName != 'insertObject') {
      apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry.innerHTML = 
        getCodeSnippet(request.wc.wc.method, request.wc.wc.params);
      //Selected API Command is not 'insertObject'
      //hide insert object button
      filePicker.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      apiRequestCodeSnippetEntry.innerHTML = 
        getCodeSnippet(request.wc.wc.method, request.wc.wc);
    }
```

The code seems to be working BUT you're losing the showing code snippet for the request part (titled API Request Code Snippet).

Someone should look into this...